# Mule 4 : Memory Management : how to manage variables having huge data for example 300 Mb?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am working on a mule application that fetches hundreds of thousands of records from database, do a  map to change the structure of the incoming records using dataweave and insert the data in Salesforce. The steps I follow are:

1. fetch all the records (> 100k) from db at once and store it in a mule variable "vars.fetchedRecords"
2. using a for each component to process these "fetchRecords" in batches of size say 10k
3. inside for each, I am using a Dataweave transformer where i use a var to hold the new mapped objects list

How to optimize this process? Will holding so many records in variables impact the performance of the application? Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Use a batch job https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-processing-concept, for-each is sequential, single threaded, batch is parallel, multi-threaded.

Comment: Ok. I will try. Another question : Where does mule store vars in RAM or Disk Storage?

Comment: Variables are stored in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that there is no need to keep records in the memory. You just have to process them all. Right?

One of the ways is to use Watermarks. Mark what you did in the database and process the rest later. Mule has inbuilt capabailiteis to work with watermarks.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/object-store/object-store-to-watermark

Even more simple way (still process records in steps) is to figure out some order (like time), work on some subset in this order (like for one year) and then start next step based on data what you already had transferred to the destination. This is even better way because if process fails you can continue it later base on the data which already was transferred. Such **pagination** process could be spread over time, over servers, over multithreads too.

The best way to save memory is not to use variables but use payload. By default Mule's payload is a stream and so it does not actually matter how big data is - it automatically flows through needle ear of the stream processing. Try to avoid storing even small pieces of the stream in variables/memory. Eventually this storage will overflow.

Comment: Hi @Alex, i fetch records from source database in a specific size say 100 records each time, process these records, save data and clear variables before I fetch the next batch. Is it the correct way of implementing pagination technique?

Comment: And most importantly what I want to understand is the memory usage of Mule applications when it retrieves data from databases and store it in a vars. Is the vars stored in RAM or disk storage? Can we free the memory by deleting the variables using Remove Variable Transformer?

Comment: Yes, fetch and process set of recoreds is correct way. Second - try to avoid storing data in variables - they are in memory. Use payload - it goes as stream and so it is only partially in memory - only small part of it. Third - sure you can use Remove Variable nut it usually done automatically in the end of the flow or other scope like inside for-each. Again, better use streams and, BTW, they are default in Mule. Jusy don't use varaiables.

Comment: What Alex is talking about when he talks about streams, which has a lot to do with the memory: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/database-connector-examples#stream-large-results

Comment: Thank you Alex for the suggestions. I will try those to improve the performance.